# Poisson Mean Problem

Tags: probability

The number of home runs in a baseball game is assumed to have a Poisson
distribution with a mean of 3. As a promotion, a company pledges to donate $10,000 to charity
for each home run hit up to a maximum of 3. Find the expected amount that the company will
donate. Another company pledges to donate C for each home run over 3 hit during the game,
and C is chosen so that the second company's expected donation is the same as the first. Find C.

I tried this:

The first part is easy

Let Y be the first company's donation we have:

$E[Y]=(0)(0.0498)+(10000)(0.1494)+(20000)(0.2240)+(30000)(.2240+.1680.........)$

then

$=(0)(0.0498)+(10000)(0.1494)+(20000)(0.2240)+(30000)(1-0.0498-0.1494-0.2240)= 23278$

My problem is here

$23278 = (C)p(4)+(2C)p(5)+(3C)p(6)+................ $

How can I solve this??

Thanks for your help, have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not checked your numerical work, and look only at your specific question about the sum 
$$p(4)+2p(5)+3p(6)+4p(7)+\cdots.$$
Call this number $x$. Add $3p(4)+3p(5)+3p(6)+3p(7)+\cdots$ to $x$. Note that $3p(4)+3p(5)+3p(6)+3p(7)+\cdots$  is quite easy to evaluate, it is just $3$ times the tail probability that you know how to calculate.  Call this number $a$.
Then 
$$a+x=4p(4)+5p(5)+6p(6)+7p(7)+\cdots.\tag{1}$$
The right-hand side of (1) is easy to evaluate. It is almost the mean $3$ of our Poisson, all that is missing is $p(1)+2p(2)+3p(3)$.

Now I think you have all the ingredients. Happy calculating! It will be fairly quick, particularly if you take advantage of some cancellation.

Comment: I did my " Happy calculating" ha ha ,  and my final result is 3p(0)+2p(1)+p(2)=3(0.0498)+2(0.1494)+(0.2240)=0.6722 then c=23278/0.6722 = 34630 and yes the book´s answer is 34630 thanks alot :D

Comment: You are welcome. Happy it went well, for selfish reasons: was not looking forward to computing if there was a glitch in your calculations.